# Insert only enabled textboxes into MySQL in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am creating an inventory management system in VB.Net, where the basic function is the process incoming invoices. I would like to insert data into my remote MySQL database but only if the textbox is considered enabled. I have no issue inserting data into the database when I want it to insert all fields. But I would like to have checkboxes enable certain products and allow the employees to enter only specific items. The check boxes do enable and disable the text fields as required but when inserting data into the database it will enter null values for all product types and I don't want it doing that as it will mess up the invoicing system. Currently I tried an if then statement but the issue I ran into was that it wanted the not enabled textboxes to be defined.
Code for what I tried is:

```
Public Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

    Dim mysqlconn as new MySqlConnection ("ServerConnection")
    mysqlconn.Open()
    dim mysqlCmd as new MysqlCommand
    mysqlcmd.Connection = MysqlConn
    
    mysqlcmd.CommandText = "Insert into Table_Name (Column1,Column2,Column3) Values (@rec1,@Rec2,@Rec3)"
    
    If txtTextbox1.Enabled = True then
        mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rec1",Column1.text)
    End If
    
    If txtTextBox2.Enabled = True then
        mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Rec2,Column2.text)
    End IF
    
    IF txtTextBox3.Enabled = True then
        mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Rec3,Column3.text)
    End If
```

Comment: Your question is not that understandable for me. AFAIK from your description, there could be a misunderstanding. If you insert into Table_Name, all Column1, Column2 and Column3 will have a value in the new row, even if it is only NULL, no matter if the ColumnX is mentionned in the INSERT sql statement. This is the basic behavior of relational database management systems. I do not undestand your aim, perhaps better explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just insert a column without a row. So if you will insert one column, you must insert all columns. If you don't want to add a value, then the column could be NULL or empty string, depending on the columns in the database. Also use `Using` and take the database work off the UI with `Async/Await`

```vb
Public Async Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    ' if your columns take NULL to mean no value
    Await AddParams(
        If(txtTextbox1.Enabled, Column1.Text, Nothing),
        If(txtTextbox2.Enabled, Column2.Text, Nothing),
        If(txtTextbox3.Enabled, Column3.Text, Nothing))
    ' else, if an empty string means no value
    Await AddParams(
        If(txtTextbox1.Enabled, Column1.Text, ""),
        If(txtTextbox2.Enabled, Column2.Text, ""),
        If(txtTextbox3.Enabled, Column3.Text, ""))
End Sub

Private Function AddParams(param1 As String, param2 As String, param3 As String) As Task
    Return Task.Run(
    Sub()
        Using mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection("ServerConnection")
            mysqlconn.Open()
            Using mysqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("Insert into Table_Name (Column1,Column2,Column3) Values (@rec1,@Rec2,@Rec3)", mysqlconn)
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rec1", param1)
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rec2", param2)
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rec3", param3)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub)
End Function
```

If I understand your current design,

**Table_Name**

| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | def | ghi |
| 2 | jkl | mno | pqr |

An incomplete invoice has empty string or NULL when one column isn't enabled

| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | *NULL* | ghi |
| 2 | *NULL* | mno | pqr |

This is what this answer does.

If your database design is flexible, perhaps a better design would be

**Invoice**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Invoice 1 |
| 2 | Invoice 2 |

**InvoiceRec**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Column1 |
| 2 | Column2 |
| 3 | Column3 |

**InvoiceItem**

| ID | InvoiceID | InvoiceRecID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | abc |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | ghi |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | mno |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | pqr |

Now you aren't storing any null when an item is not enabled. The SQL to select would then be

```sql
SELECT 
    i.Name InvoiceName
    , ir.Name InvoiceRecName
    , ii.Value Value
FROM InvoiceItem ii
INNER JOIN Invoice i ON i.ID = ii.InvoiceID
INNER JOIN InvoiceRec ir ON i.ID = ir.InvoiceRecID
WHERE i.Name = 'Invoice 1'
```

| InvoiceName | InvoiceRecName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Invoice 1 | Column1 | abc |
| Invoice 1 | Column3 | ghi |

This would totally invalidate the code I wrote (except keep the `Async` and `Using`) and you'd need to query multiple tables before making multiple inserts, but the design would be normalized and database storage size would be reduced.

Further, you can build your UI from the metadata tables [Invoice] and [InvoiceRec] so if wanted to add another InvoiceRec to your business, you can add in SQL, and the UI will not need to be modified.

Comment: Oh, I left that part out. I have 11 products on the page all enabled with check boxes. The check boxes enable the Item quantity field and a preset read only textbox with the Item code. Currently when the enter button is hit it enters all the product codes even if they are not enabled and sets them to null values. I don't want it to enter the product codes that aren't enabled because then it will send all those null values to the invoice. Though I see what you are saying and I'm wondering if I should change my approach entirely. But I will try what you suggested and see if that helps anything.

Comment: @ACCStudios What does a row in the database look like where not all the product codes are enabled?

Comment: @ACCStudios not sure if you can modify your design, but I added an alternative to the answer. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I can change the design to be whatever it needs to be. I also as I was working on trying out the original code realized it would likely be better to just let it store the data and then use multiple tables. The main function we need the program to do is only have to enter data once, and have it transmit to all the different places required because right now employees have to enter the data multiple times in multiple locations which can cause errors and wastes time. So maybe just multiple queries is the way to solve this rather than the entry code itself, like you did above.